# Spring elasticsearch - Map<String, String> index

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an object that contains a Map<String, String> field:

```
@Document(indexName = "custom-creative-template")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/custom-creative-template-index.json")
public class CustomCreativeTemplateIndexDto {
    Map<String, String> customValues;
}
```

When querying data for this index, I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.String!
```

When using Map<String, Object> however, it works.

That's the `Settings` file for the index:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "sortable": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried setting the `FieldType` in the `Field` annotation to `FieldType.Text` & `FieldType.Flattened` but I keep getting the same error.

`Mappings`:

```
{
  "custom-creative-template": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "customValues": {
          "properties": {
            "offerBullets": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
           "offerDescription": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "key": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "sort": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "sortable"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: settings is irrelevant here, what's the mapping for that index? How is data inserted into the index? By your application or somehow else?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I have added the mapping for the index. Yes data is inserted by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with field type object:

```java
@Document(indexName = "custom-creative-template")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/custom-creative-template-index.json")
public class CustomCreativeTemplateIndexDto {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    Map<String, String> customValues;
}
```